# How do I calculate all the resting positions of the differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's given differential equation

$\dot{x}=p$

$\dot{y}=-x^3+x$

How do I calculate  all the resting positions of the differential equation?

I can calculate resting points of two differential equation.

For example.

$p=0$

$x_1=-1,x_2=0,x_3=1$

Is this correct?

Comment: do you mean $\dot{x} = y$? as this looks like a familiar equation.

Comment: What is $p$? is it a constant?

Comment: No, I don't mean @Chinny84

Comment: It's not written in example if it is constant @JackyChong

Comment: So $\dot{x}=$ the derivative of $x$?  And if so, with respect to what?

Comment: Yes, it's derivative. Also it's not written. @SimpleArt

Answer (score 1):

By resting position, I assume you mean to say $\dot{x}=\dot{y}=0$.  This gives us

$$p=0$$

$$0=-x^3+x=-x(x+1)(x-1)\implies x=-1,0,1$$

And those are all solutions.